# PHP null while trying to get id of the row

Tags: php

I am having strange trouble

i have this result

```
{"Result":{"id":"1010","venueId":"29","type":"1004","name":"Bacardi"}}
```

with code

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM spirits WHERE venueId = :venueId');
            $statement->bindParam(':venueId' , $venueId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->execute();

            $row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $spirits = $row;
            $spirit = $spirits[0];
            return json_encode(array('Result'=>$spirit));
```

Now the problem is

when i try to do `$drinkId = $spirit->id`;
it returns null..
what is wrong?

```
var_dump($row[0]);

array(4) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1010" ["venueId"]=> string(2) "29" ["type"]=> string(4) "1004" ["name"]=> string(7) "Bacardi" }
```

Comment: Did you try basic debugging, such as `var_dump($row[0]);`?

Comment: $spirit result is as above, $row or $spirits are not null

Comment: No its not json encoded. I am encoding it later. Please check about the result of var_dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because you use [`FETCH_ASSOC`](http://php.net/manual/it/pdostatement.fetch.php), and thus the call should be

```
$drinkId = $spirit['id'];
```

Try with `FETCH_OBJ` instead

Answer (score 0):

In the most boiled down explanation, the problem is that you are fetching your database results as an associative array (`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`). If you want to access your row data using the object operator, you need to fetch your results as an object, or into a specific class.

Without modifying your code, to access the ID of the first returned row, you would do:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM spirits WHERE venueId = :venueId');
$statement->bindParam(':venueId' , $venueId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();

$row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$spirit = $row[0];
$drinkId = $spirit['id'];
```

Or you could fetch into an instance of `stdClass` and use the object operator, like so:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM spirits WHERE venueId = :venueId');
$statement->bindParam(':venueId' , $venueId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();

$row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$spirit = $row[0];
$drinkId = $spirit->id;
```